# Generate Synthetic keys to map many to many relationship

Tags: python-3.x, t-sql, pyspark

Iam trying to create a unique synthetic key after identifying relationships between original keys.

My DataFrame:

```
Key   Value
K1     1
K2     2
K2     3
K1     3
K2     4
K1     5
K3     6
K4     6
K5     7
```

Expected Result:

```
Key   Value   New_Key
K1     1        NK1
K2     2        NK1
K2     3        NK1
K1     3        NK1
K2     4        NK1 
K1     5        NK1 
K2     6        NK2
K3     6        NK2
K4     7        NK3
```

I look forward to a response in python 3.0 or pyspark.

I tried it with this code:

```py
#Import libraries# 
import networkx as nx 
import pandas as pd 
#Create DF# 
d1=pd.DataFrame({'Key','Value'}) 
#Create Empty Graph# 
G=nx.Graph() 
#Create a list of edge tuples# 
e=list(d1.iloc[0:].itertuples(index=False, name=None)) 
#Create a list of nodes/vertices# 
v=list(set(d1.A).union(set(d1.B))) 
#Add nodes and edges to the graph# 
G.add_edges_from(e) 
G.add_nodes_from(v) 
#Get list connected components# 
c=[c for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=None, reverse=False)] print(c)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please add what you tried by yourself. Secondly, please explain the logic you want to apply. Why does all rows except of the K4 got `NK1` as new key? It is not clear for me.

Comment: @cronoik Well, I did posted my code but then didn't receive any response so I thought maybe my code is adding complexity to the question. hence, i edited my OP  and just mentioned what I am looking for.

Comment: @cronoik To you second question, I had tried to solve my problem using adjacency matrix graph but couldn't ouput desired result. All rows except the last are interlinked either because of 'key' or because of their 'Value', hence, basically they are 1 customer. For the Last row, it is a different customer as neither key or value link back to any of the previous rows, hence, assigned a new key. Hope this helps.

Comment: @cronoik you can refer to python's networkx package as starters

Comment: `All rows except the last are interlinked either because of 'key' or because of their 'Value', hence, basically they are 1 customer. For the Last row, it is a different customer as neither key or value link back to any of the previous rows, hence, assigned a new key.` that is really helpful information, but could you please check your example again? Your expected result doesn't matches your given input (e.g. K3 and K4 get a different key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to solve can known as a graph problem called connected components. All you have to do is to treat your `Keys` and `Values` as vertices and run an connected components algorithm. The following shows you a solution with pyspark and [graphframes](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/index.html).

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from graphframes import *

sc.setCheckpointDir('/tmp/graphframes')

l = [('K1' ,    1),
('K2' ,    2),
('K2' ,    3),
('K1' ,    3),
('K2' ,    4),
('K1' ,    5),
('K3' ,    6),
('K4' ,    6),
('K5' ,    7)]

columns = ['Key', 'Value']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

#creating a graphframe 
#an edge dataframe requires a src and a dst column
edges = df.withColumnRenamed('Key', 'src')\
          .withColumnRenamed('Value', 'dst')

#a vertices dataframe requires a id column
vertices = df.select('Key').union(df.select('value')).withColumnRenamed('Key', 'id')

#this creates a graphframe...
g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
#which already has a function called connected components
cC = g.connectedComponents().withColumnRenamed('id', 'Key')

#now we join the connectedComponents dataframe with the original dataframe to add the new keys to it. I'm calling distinct here, as I'm currently getting multiple rows which I can't really explain at the moment
df = df.join(cC, 'Key', 'inner').distinct()
df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+---+-----+------------+ 
|Key|Value|   component| 
+---+-----+------------+ 
| K3|    6|335007449088| 
| K1|    5|154618822656| 
| K1|    1|154618822656| 
| K1|    3|154618822656| 
| K2|    2|154618822656| 
| K2|    3|154618822656| 
| K2|    4|154618822656| 
| K4|    6|335007449088| 
| K5|    7| 25769803776| 
+---+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this is what I was looking for , Unfortunately I am unable to test it on my enterprise Spark cluster as the lib graphframes is missing and I cannot add it to my user id. I have tried to convert this to the below python code to run locally but I am stuck at the last step of creating pesudo keys after determining connections.

Comment: #Import libraries#
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

#Create DF#
d1=pd.DataFrame({'Key','Value'})

#Create Empty Graph#
G=nx.Graph()

#Create a list of edge tuples#
e=list(d1.iloc[0:].itertuples(index=False, name=None))

#Create a list of nodes/vertices#
v=list(set(d1.A).union(set(d1.B)))

#Add nodes and edges to the graph#
G.add_edges_from(e)
G.add_nodes_from(v)

#Get list connected components#
c=[c for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=None, reverse=False)]
print(c)

Comment: my apologies for the above format, for some reason, I am unable to format my code

Comment: I have added your code to your initial question. Could you please accept my edit? I will have a look and extend my answer with a non graphframes solution.

Comment: edit accepted, thank you again for investing your time.

Comment: @vagautam: Have a look at this [code](https://mlwhiz.com/blog/2018/12/07/connected_components/#connected-components-in-pyspark). Open another question if you have problems with it.

Comment: new question link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085669/python-code-to-get-connected-components-in-graph-analysis-without-using-graphframes